# Package system broken after CUDA installation attempt Ubunutu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I had some trouble with GROMACS not recognizing my graphics card when my drivers were updated automatically which led to a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04. The problems persisted so I thought I would install CUDA and compile GROMACS manually.

I started with CUDA, following the online [guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#pre-installation-actions) for Ubuntu and I ran:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb
```

and i then tried installing CUDA by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

I got an error:

```
(gconftool-2:24440): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon: //bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: No protocol specified Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.

Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ... Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1) ... E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and then I started getting errors from the Ubuntu Software Centre saying that the package system is broken. From what I understand this was caused due to the nvidia repository.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

but to no avail. I got:

Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-opencl-icd-346_346.46-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-opencl-icd-346 (346.46-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-opencl-icd-346_346.46-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd', which is also in package nvidia-opencl-icd-331 331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

and

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers:
 cuda-drivers depends on nvidia-opencl-icd-346 (>= 346.46); however:
  Package nvidia-opencl-icd-346 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-runtime-7-0:
 cuda-runtime-7-0 depends on cuda-drivers (>= 346.46); however:
  Package cuda-drivers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-runtime-7-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-7-0:
 cuda-7-0 depends on cuda-runtime-7-0 (= 7.0-28); however:
  Package cuda-runtime-7-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-7-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda:
 cuda depends on cuda-7-0 (= 7.0-28); however:
  Package cuda-7-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cuda-drivers
 cuda-runtime-7-0
 cuda-7-0
 cuda

I also tried removing the nvidia repository by trying:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb
```

but I got:

Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

I don't know what to do to fix it. Any ideas please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked, just removed the nvidia repository as described here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository